# cordova edit-config not updating AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap, cordova-cli

I am trying to update the `AndroidManifest.xml` file with the following in config.xml:

```
<platform name="android">
  <edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application">
  <application android:icon="@mipmap/appicons" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/appicons_round" />
  </edit-config>
</platform>
```

and it doesn't update anything. I tried to remove the full path and just leave it as file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" and that's also not working. I am using command line with Android 7.0.0 and I'm absolutely lost.

Both `config.xml` and `AndroidManifest.xml` pass XML tests.

If I update AndroidManifest.xml manually with the changes, the app runs fine and all changes are visible, but I believe that's not the proper way of doing it.

I am completely lost..

UPDATE:
Could it be related to this?
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-13514?jql=text%20~%20%22edit-config%22

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found the solution! `<edit-config` apparently cannot be inside the `<platform></platform>` tags. It has to be outside of it and it will work. Like this:

```
<edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application">
  <application android:icon="@mipmap/appicons" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/appicons_round" />
</edit-config>

<platform name="android">
  ...
</platform>
```

Hope this helps someone else save a few hours.

Comment: To add to this, On one machine it worked fine (cordova 8.1.2), but on another machine it was not working (cordova 8.0.0). I didn't want to remove platform entirely as other platforms had warnings but what I found worked for me was moving <edit-config> into the very first <platform name="android"> in the config file.

Comment: It worked with cordova 10.0.0